# Discord Bot Raising Type Error With Class

Tags: python, class, discord.py, typeerror

I created a Python Discord Bot, I put all the functions into a class but when I did I started getting a Type Error, only thing is the error is telling me to do exactly what I did.
Here is the affected code and the error.

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='--', case_insensitive=True)



class Settings:

    def __init__(self):
        self.spitfirerole = 917086768736649258
        with open("data.json") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        f.close()

        self.prev = data["serial"]

    @client.event
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('ThatOneGuy is online.')
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="chess with Mr.Z"))
        channel = client.get_channel(918300328267497502)
        em = discord.Embed(title=f"Status", color=0x22ff12)
        em.add_field(name="Active", value=f"I am now searching for a Spitfire.")
        await channel.send(f"<@&{self.spitfirerole}>", embed=em)
```

The error;

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Libra\PycharmProjects\ThatOneGuy\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_ready() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: Look at the examples. The on_ready() method do not expect a parameter https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html

Comment: I should clarify, there is more code that uses the ```self``` argument. So if I remove it, I will get more errors.

Comment: I think you need separate to code in a way that the pydiscord event methods respect the parameters defined on the documentation

Answer (score 2):

When an `on_ready` handler is registered with `@client.event`, it's expected to be a function that takes no arguments.  If you want your `on_ready` to be a method in a class, you'll need to make it a static method:

```
    @client.event
    @staticmethod
    async def on_ready():
        print('ThatOneGuy is online.')
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="chess with Mr.Z"))
```

If it needs to be an instance method, you probably want to subclass `discord.Client` (or `commands.Bot`) rather than using `@client.event`:

```
class Settings(commands.Bot):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('ThatOneGuy is online.')
        await self.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="chess with Mr.Z"))

client = Settings(command_prefix='--', case_insensitive=True)
```

Another possibility would be having a global `on_ready` that takes no arguments and delegates to your Settings instance:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='--', case_insensitive=True)
settings = Settings()

@client.event
def on_ready():
    settings.on_ready()
```

Comment: Didn't work. Self needs to be defined right?

Comment: There is no `self` in a static method -- and when you register a handler with `@client.event`, you're registering it on the function, not on a method of a particular instance (hence there's no `self` unless the caller provides one -- which it doesn't, hence your `TypeError`).

Comment: Now the bot won't even start up.

Comment: Another possibility might be doing `client.event(settings.on_ready)`, where `settings` is your `Settings` instance.  Not sure if that's actually a supported pattern.

Comment: So how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Undo the change you made that made the bot not start up, and then try something else?

Comment: Looking more closely at your code and at the doc, I can see that if you want to do the subclassing thing, you probably need to subclass `commands.Bot` (which is itself a subclass of `discord.Client`).  Not sure what error you were hitting before, but that might fix it.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Well this code is actually longer then what I entered, the error occurred when I turned everything into a class. I can think of a work around but I would really like to keep the class. If you don't have any other idea. I will try the alternative.

Comment: Is your class a subclass of `discord.Client` and/or `commands.Bot`?  It seems like if you make a method an event handler the idea is for it to be on a subclass of `Client`.

Comment: Also this is my first time using a class so I don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: This is probably not an ideal use case for learning OOP.

Comment: I don't know what a subclass is.

Comment: Avoid making this a class IMO.  :)

Comment: Alright, I will try that.